# Position custom legend in Recharts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, recharts

I have the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/q3dmy4?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A20%2C1) using react, tailwind, and Recharts. I have a custom legend component that is generated in the `renderLenged()` function. I want to position the legend entries vertically and have them showing on the right side of the pie chart in the middle. I've tried to add absolute positioning to the `renderLegend` component, but it pushes the legend outside of the `ResponsiveContainer` and I have to use negative positioning IE `T-[-250px] R-[-20px]` on the `renderLegend` component to bring it back into proper positioning which is something I don't want to rely on. How would I go about fixing this? Right now the legend is on the bottom and horizontal. Thanks

As explained, I tried to add `absolute` positioning to the `<renderLegend />` component, but it pushed the legend outside of the chart container. Also tried to mess with the various props that `<Legend />` component has such as `VerticalAlign="middle"` but was not able to get it to work and it displaces the pie chart. I want to see if we can somehow use absolute positioning properly without relying on negative positioning to get the end result.